# Reference for the bordered Hessian method

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, hessian-matrix

I need a reference for the proof of the bordered Hessian test. I know how to use it, but I kinda learned it "in the wild" and need a **standard** good reference for its proof to add to my references section. I tried to google for it, but I only found tons and tons of manuscripts teaching how to use it via computation examples, with no proofs/books.